# Size of access token in EWS

Tags: oauth, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Service (EWS) for OAUTH authentication for my application. I set the size of the access token to 2048 bytes. A few weeks ago, the application stopped working and was giving Error 401. I increased the size of the access to 3000 bytes. It has started working again.
I’m am using an AcuCOBOL and C++ DLL combination for authentication. Could anybody provide the precise size of the acess token which EWS uses?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no size limit - JWT token embeds a lot of information in addition to the digital signature; take a look at your tokens at https://jwt.ms

Practically, of course, 4k-5k would be a reasonable DB field size limit.